# Combining multiple groups of text files with bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder of text files that are labelled something like this:

```
0filename1
1filename1
2filename1
....
0filename2
1filename2
2filename2
....
```

et cetera. What I want to do is take all the files that end in filename1 and combine them all into a file named filename1, and similarly for filename2 and all other files. Normally I would do something like this

```
cat [0123456789]*filename1 > filename1
```

and just repeat the command for every different file name I have. However, I want to be able to automate this. The exact form of the file names change regularly, so it's not as simple as just writing a script that will do the above command for filename1, filename2, etc. The length of the file names do stay constant though, so I suspect the right way to automate this would be for a script to take every file that has the same last *n* characters in the filename and copy them into a file with the name of these *n* characters. I'm not sure how to do this though - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty simple, just need to filter the files to get the 'base' strings.

```
for $base in $( ls | cut -b 1-8 | sort -u ); do
    cat [0123456789]*$base > $base
done
```

where `1-8` is the characters you intend to *keep*, so <consistent length of filenames> - <N last characters that vary instead of `8`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit more *complex* solution that handles files with whitespace characters, with multi-digit numbers or flexible filename length:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob nullglob

files=(+([0-9])?*)
(( ${#files[@]} )) || exit 1

while IFS= read -rd '' filename; do
    printf '%s\0' +([0-9])"$filename" | sort -zn | xargs -0 cat > "$filename"
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${files[@]##+([0-9])}" | sort -zu)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

str="filename"
for i in {1..2}
do
    cat {?,??}"${str}${i}" > "${str}${i}"
done
```

Script uses Bash Expansion `{..}` and character wildcard `?` to expand the available filenames. If you have `0filename1` to `9filename1`, then use a single `?` and use `??` for `10filename1-99filename1`.

Example:

```
$ cat 0filename1 
011
$ cat 1filename1 
111
$ cat 2filename1 
211
$ cat 10filename1 
1011
$ cat 0filename2
022
$ cat 1filename2
122
$ cat 2filename2
222
$ cat 10filename2
1022
```

Output of the above script would be:

```
$ cat filename1
011
111
211
1011

$ cat filename2
022
122
222
1022
```